# Create Title Page with Hepthesis produces error

Tags: titles, thesis, hepthesis

I'm trying to create a title page with `hepthesis` but run into problems. Could you hint me in the direction where I skrewed up?

MWE1:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,]{hepthesis}

\begin{document}
\author{QWER QWER}
\title{ABC acb}
\date{1.1.2000}

\begin{titlepage}
        BlaBla
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

procudes: `! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.`

MWE2:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,]{hepthesis}

\begin{document}
\author{QWER QWER}
\title{ABC acb}
\date{1.1.2000}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
        asdf
    \end{minipage}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

produces the same with a lot of additional errors which migth go away once I takle the problem. Omitting the lines of `author/title/date` didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `hepthesis`, there is no `titlepage` environment, but a `\titlepage` command, see section 6.5 in the class documentation.

The optional command is not really optional, because its absence will still cause the `There's no line here to end`, telling me that the class has not really been fully tested. Also, an input such as

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,]{hepthesis}

\begin{document}
\author{QWER QWER}
\title{ABC acb}
\date{1.1.2000}

\titlepage[Some affiliation]{%
  A dissertation submitted to the University of Somewhere\\
  for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy
}

\end{document}
```

will produce the following typographically disputable result:

[image]

A sounder definition of `\titlepage` would be

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,]{hepthesis}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\titlepage}[2][]{%
  \par
  \begingroup
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \ifx\@sftitles\@empty\else\sffamily\fi%
  \centering
  \vspace*{\frontmattertitleskip}%
  \begin{doublespace}%
  \Huge\textbf{\thetitle}\\
  \end{doublespace}%
  \vspace*{3cm}%
  {\Large\theauthor\\[1ex]}
  {#1\par}
  \vspace*{8cm}%
  {#2\\}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\author{QWER QWER}
\title{ABC acb}
\date{1.1.2000}

\titlepage[Some affiliation]{%
A dissertation submitted to the University of Somewhere\\
for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy
}

\end{document}
```

This will work also without the optional argument.

[image]

Comment: Okey Thank you for your answer, I'll use the renewcommand as my titlepage environment now. Seems a bit hacky but this might work.